# print the length of the longest string in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

I am having difficulties print the length of the longest string in the list which is kevin07 which should equal to 7.

My current solution prints all 3 item lengths.

```
names = ['ron', 'james', 'kevin07']

best = 0

for index in range(len(names)):
    if len(names[index]) > best:
        best = len(names[index])
        print(best)
```

Comment: Move `print(best)` *outside* of the loop?

Comment: `max([len(i) for i in names])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names = ['ron', 'james', 'kevin07']

best = 0

for index in range(len(names)):
    if len(names[index]) > best:
        best = len(names[index])

print(best)
```

Output:

```
7
```

Explanation:

You need to move the print(best) outside of loop

Comment: @Tomble: It is added according to your code and tested it worked. Let me know if it solves your issue. ?

Comment: Thanks. Yea, i had my print statement in the wrong place. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Tomble: Mention your vote if you got desired information/code

Answer (score 9):

You're trying to find the maximum by length:

```
item = max(names, key=len)
print(len(item))
```

You could also be a bit more direct:

```
print(max(len(x) for x in names))
```

...though you won't know what the item is if you decide to go this way.

Answer (score 3):

```py
print(max(map(len, names)))
```

Use map function.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
names = ['ron', 'james', 'kevin07']
best = max([len(i) for i in names])
print(best)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this approach that solves your problem:

```
names = ['ron', 'james', 'kevin07']

best = 0

for name in names:
    if len(name) > best:
        best = len(name)

print(best)
```

The main problem with your code was that you printed `best` in every step of you loop.

The other thing I changed is the proper usage of a range-based loop. There is actually no need to access the elements of you list via index.

Comment: Thanks. Yea, i had my print statement in the wrong place. Thanks for your help